# for each row of csv file print the nth column of every row using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My csv file looks like this :

```
Date,Client_mnenonic,summary,Assignee
2021-01-22,P1,Q1 Non-Prod Quarterly Maintenance,Karthik
18.01.21,P2,Q1 Non-Prod Quarterly Maintenance,Jimmi
18.01.21,P3,Q1 Non-Prod Quarterly Maintenance,Abdul
18.01.21,P4,Q1 Non-Prod Quarterly Maintenance,Naresh
18.01.21,P5,Q1 Non-Prod Quarterly Maintenance,Roy
```

I want to traverse through this csv file and print 3rd column of every row:

my code looks like this:

```
require 'csv'

table = CSV.parse(File.read("file.csv"), headers: true)
table.each do |row column|
  puts row[0]column[3]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, the syntax is wrong.

```
require 'csv'

table = CSV.parse(File.read("test.csv"), headers: true)
table.each do |row|
  # using index position
  puts row[2]

  # OR using header
  puts row['summary']
end
```

Parsing CSV with `headers` gives an instance of `CSV::Row` which can be accessed two ways

1. Using Index
2. Using header name

Comment: Here is my function, I want to run for loop for each of csv row and print the colums values of that rows, how can I do it?


def create_issue
table = CSV.parse(File.read("file.csv"), headers: true)
    client = JIRA::Client.new(@jira_creds)
    issue = client.Issue.build
    field_list = {"fields" => {
    "summary" => table.by_row[1][2],
    "customfield_10604" => table.by_row[0][1],
    "duedate" => table.by_row[0][0]
   }}
end